# Storing data in Nested structure in Shared Preferences xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences

I have been trying store some data on Shared Preferences like in this format below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
    <map>
        <set name="01">
            <string name="id">01</string>
            <string name="mobile">123456789</string>
            <string name="name">name_1</string>
        </set>
        <set name="02">
           <string name="id">02</string>
           <string name="mobile">987654321</string>
           <string name="name">name_2</string>
        </set>
    </map>
```

But I couldn't achieve this task by below code.

```
    Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();
    Map<String, String> lhm =  new LinkedHashMap<>();

        lhm.put("id",id);
        lhm.put("name",name);
        lhm.put("mobile",mobile);
        lhm.put("password",password);

        stringSet.addAll(?);

        editor.putStringSet(nic,stringSet);

        editor.apply();
```

this `addAll()` method only receives a collection. is there anyway to pass a Map to that method? Or Is there any other way to achieve my storage structure format?

Comment: Not out of the box. If you want to use `SharedPreferences` for this then I'd suggest serialising your data (either yourself or with a serialisation library like `GSON`) and storing the resultant `String`

Comment: Map is also part of collection classes. What's the exact issue ?